# nodejs decrease v8 garbage collector memory usage

Tags: node.js, memory-management, garbage-collection, v8

I'm debugging a nodejs application with [util](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html) module and while **heapUsed** value stays around 30-100MB, **heapTotal** value grows up to 1.4GB.

[Here is a question about similar behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712220/node-js-process-uses-1-4-gb-of-memory-but-heapdump-is-only-300-mb)

I've read that this is the way how v8 garbage collector behaves, but the question is how to decrease the amount of memory it allocates (make it less than 1.4GB) if running on 512 MB device for example

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to control the max memory size flags (all sizes are taken in MB).

The [recommended amounts for a "low memory device" are](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/2b17c752d117bf0ededd23206bb38b69e641a976/src/heap/heap.h#L1106-L1136):

```
node --max-executable-size=96 --max-old-space-size=128 --max-semi-space-size=1 app.js
```

for 32-bit and/or Android and

```
node --max-executable-size=192 --max-old-space-size=256 --max-semi-space-size=2 app.js
```

for 64-bit non-android.

These would limit the heap totals to 225mb and 450mb respectively. It doesn't include memory usage outside JS. For instance buffers are allocated as "c memory" , not in the JavaScript heap.

Also you should know that the closer you are to the heap limit the more time is wasted in GC. E.g. if you are at 95% memory usage 90% of the CPU would be used for GC and 10% for running actual code (not real numbers but give the general idea). So you should be as generous as possible with the limits and never exceed say 16% of the maximum memory usage (I.E. `heapUsed/limit` should not be greater than `0.16`). 16% is just something I recall from some paper, it might not be the most optimal.

Flags:

- `--max-executable-size` the maximum size of heap reserved for executable code (the native code result of just-in-time compiled JavaScript).
- `--max-old-space-size` the maximum size of heap reserved for long term objects
- `--max-semi-space-size` the maximum size of heap reserved for short term objects

Comment: testing it on 64bit ubuntu, and now heapTotal stays around 260 - 280MB, wondering where do these numbers come from?

Comment: @Herokiller which numbers?

Comment: heapTotal for your 2nd example is around 280MB for the same test which was 1.4GB before

Comment: I don't understand your question, the entire point was to use the flags to reduce total memory v8 will use for js

Comment: Can you please explain flags ?

Comment: −1 Please explain what the flags do and what's their purpose, otherwise your answer is incomplete.

Comment: @losnir the flags control the size of js heap and that is their purpose :)?

Comment: @Esailija It's much more clearer now for everyone who comes from Google and has no background about V8 memory management / GC. +1

Comment: If you could, please explain the math behind the numbers you chose for those two devices

Comment: It looks like --max-executable-size is no longer an option